# Check the load factor of foo = {'foo':1,'zip':2,'zam':3,'bar':4}

Tags: python

Suppose such a associated array,

```
foo = {'foo':1,'zip':2,'zam':3,'bar':4}
```

How could I check the load factor of hash table?

Comment: What do you mean by load factor?

Comment: Load factor = total number of items / table size. As i know the smallest table size in python dict is 8

Comment: ty, could you please transmit the succinct comment to answer. @Artemiy

Comment: The `dict` type does not make any such information available.  There not even a guarantee that the implementation of `dict` is something for which "load factor" is a meaningful concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load factor = total number of items / hash table size. As i know the smallest table size in cpython 3.6 dict [is 8](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L111) with no more than 5 active entries

Comment: This isn't enough to check the load factor, since dict's don't expose the table size.

Comment: It is, but i didn't say that it would be enough, but it seems in case of 4 active entries as in the example it will be

Answer (score 0):

While the formula depends on the (C)Python version and pointer size (and sometimes even the types of the keys!), you can measure this with `sys.getsizeof()`.  The exact numbers that follow are for a 64-bit build.

In Python **2** it's pretty straightforward: 280 B for the `PyDictObject` (whose capacity is always 8) and its `PyGC_Head`, so the capacity is

```
def cap2(d): return (sys.getsizeof(d)-280)/24 or 8
```

Dictionaries in this version grow by quadrupling, or doubling if they're large.

In Python **3** before 3.6, there's a constant overhead of 96 B (except for so-called "split tables" used to share attribute names among class instances), so it's

```
def cap3(d): return (sys.getsizeof(d)-96)//24
```

Dictionaries (by version 3.5) grow by doubling (when there are no deletions).

Since **3.6**, the overhead is 112 B.  The further storage is more complicated because the actual hash table stores only indices and they are of variable size.  We then have to use the formula for `USABLE_FRACTION` in `dictobject.c` and work out that the space used for a table capacity of 2^*n* (*n*>=3) is

```
112+(1<<n)*(n//8+1)+(1<<n+1)//3*24
```

This is hard to invert exactly, but (given these stringent assumptions) you can approximate it as the greatest power of 2 no greater than one seventeenth(!) of the size:

```
def cap36(d):
  s=sys.getsizeof(d)//17
  n=3
  while 1<<n+1<=s: n+=1
  return n
```

Don't forget to divide `len(d)` by the capacity!

Comment: This is also going to depend on how big pointers are on your Python build (and maybe how big a C long is, too).

Comment: @user2357112: I did say "for a 64-buit build".  I don't think there are yet more variables: all the structure members are pointer-sized (or are of a fixed size for the 3.6 index table).

Comment: Ah, you did say that, just later than I expected and in a way that makes it sound like it only applies to the `cap2` function.

Comment: @user2357112: I thought it would be obvious that it carries through, but I rephrased it to be explicit.  Better?